# Updating a Value in table automatically

Tags: database, postgresql

I just started using PostgreSQL and had a doubt. I created a table

```
CREATE TABLE B2S(
                 StudentID INTEGER 
                ,Book_Issued VARCHAR(20)
                ,Issue_Date DATE
                ,Due_Date DATE
                )
```

.

I want the Due_Date to be 30 + Issue_Date . How am I supposed to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 Options to do this

- Option - 1

You can use [Date/Time Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html),

for example your Issue_Date is `2015-03-19` then Due_Date should be `2015-04-19`,So you can use `'2015-03-18'::date + interval '30' DAY` in the insert statement

```
 insert into B2S values (1,'Yes','2015-03-18','2015-03-18'::date + interval '30' DAY)
```

---

- Option 2

or you can create a function like below, Here `argIssue_date` is the value of your `Issue_Date` date and the function will returns `Due_Date`.

```
create or replace function fn_get_due_date(argIssue_date date) returns date
as
$$
select (argIssue_date::date +  interval '30' DAY)::date 
$$
language sql
```

and call this function in your insert statement

```
insert into B2S values (1,'Yes','2015-03-18',fn_get_due_date('2015-03-18'))
```

---

- Option 3

By creating a trigger, @Daniel Sagayaraj already answered about this

see the elaborated trigger for OP's question

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tgr_due_date() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
 NEW.Due_Date := NEW.Issue_Date::date +  interval ''30'' DAY;
RETURN NEW;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

assigning created trigger `tgr_due_date` to table `B2S`

```
CREATE TRIGGER due_date_insert 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON B2S 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tgr_due_date();
```

and finally the insert statement

```
insert into B2S (StudentID,Book_Issued,Issue_Date) values (1,'Yes','2015-05-18')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically update the Due_Date while inserting a new record,you can use Triggers in sql.

Example:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER trg1
    AFTER
    INSERT ON emp1
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    [logic goes here]
END;

CREATE  TRIGGER trigger_name [BEFORE|AFTER] UPDATE OF column_name
ON table_name
[
  Trigger logic goes here
];
```

Comment: Should I do one of those or both ?

Comment: This is not valid for Postgres